# JavaとCの演算子評価順序の違いについて

Tags: java, c

Javaの初学者です。

以下のCとJavaのプログラムで実行結果が異なります。
何が原因なのでしょうか。
原因に関連するキーワードなど教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

・Javaのコード

```
int a = 0;
if(a == ++a)
{
    System.out.println("equal");
}else{
    System.out.println("not equal");
}
```

実行結果
not equal

Cのコード

```
int a = 0;
if(a == ++a)
{
    printf("equal\n");
}else{
    printf("not equal\n");
}
```

実行結果
equal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javaは仕様で左辺を評価してから右辺を評価する、と決まっていたはずです。
よって常に`a == ++a`はaとそれよりも1大きい値と比較されるので偽です。

一方Cはどちらの評価が先かは未定義であったと思います。
左辺が先であればJavaと同じになりますし、右辺が先に評価された場合は`a == ++a`はaをインクリメントしてからその値自身と比較するので常に真となります。

実際gccでコンパイルしたところ、結果は`not equal`となり、他の手軽なWebサイト上のインタープリターでやってみたところ`equal`と異なる結果となりました。

(根拠となる仕様の参照先とかは、Cの方はどなたかフォローしてくれると嬉しいです)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7
Java仕様です。

Comment: なお、Cでの「未定義」の動作は、どちらを先に行なうかというようなレベルではなく、エラーにしてもいいし、鼻から悪魔を召喚してもOKというレベルで「未定義」だったりします。

Comment: 仕様とは違いますがgccで`-Wsequence-point`オプションを付けると、該当箇所に対して`warning: operation on ‘a’ may be undefined`なるエラーを吐いてくれます。マニュアルの英語版の`-Wsequence-point`の項目を見るにやはりこのことを言っているようです。

Comment: @sakuro 今回の話においては式の評価順序が未規定（Unspecified）というだけなので、そんなとんでもないことは起こらないです（起こしてはいけない）。あくまでも左辺と右辺を評価する順序が決まってない（からどちらから評価しても合法である）というだけです。

Comment: C++ でよければ 5.式 の 項目 4 に「式の中の部分式の評価順序及び副作用の発生順序については、規定しない」とあります。ただしこの後ろに「（副作用があるとき）直前の値は、次に格納すべき値を決定するためだけにアクセスされる<中略>そうでない場合、その挙動は未定義とする」となっています。最初の例は未定義動作ですね。

Comment: たくさんのフォローありがとうございます。

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi なるほど、  undefined(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) ではなくunspecified(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior) なのですね。

Comment: 演算子の評価順序と被演算子（左辺と右辺）の評価順序があって、分けて考える必要があるんですね。
話が混ざってよく分からなくなっていたので、理解が進んだ気がします。

guest0981さんが引用してくれたJavaのドキュメントにもありますが、
本件は演算子の評価順序ではなく被演算子の評価順序の話になるってことですよね。
インクリメント（単項演算子）の場合については記載がないですが、
`if(a == ++a)`
これが
`if(a == (a=a+1))`
になるから、右辺で代入が行われた事実が左辺に反映されず、not equalになるということなんですね。

Answer (score 2):

C言語についてですが、式の評価順序は実装依存となっていてequal / not equalどちらにもなり得ます。equalが得られたのは一例にすぎません。

そのため各種コンパイラーは警告を出します。

```
GCC
prog.c:4:13: warning: operation on 'a' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
    if(a == ++a)
            ^

clang
prog.c:4:13: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'a' [-Wunsequenced]
    if(a == ++a)
       ~    ^
```

（Visual C++は警告を出さないようです。）